# I'm getting an error with .push in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting an unexpected token error with this code:

```
   var $_POST = $form.serializeArray();  //  put form posts into an array
    var $_POST.push({name:'ajax', value:$form.attr('action').split('=').pop()});
    var $_POST.push({name:$submit.attr('name'), value:$submit.attr('value')});
```

I'm running jquery 3.3.1

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mistakenly have `var` preceding your `push` expressions:

```
var $_POST = $form.serializeArray();  //  put form posts into an array
$_POST.push({name:'ajax', value:$form.attr('action').split('=').pop()});
$_POST.push({name:$submit.attr('name'), value:$submit.attr('value')});
```

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. I used to work, but then I modified the code a bit. And added the `var` for some reason. Thanks :)